# How To request a HTML file from an URL with strange DTD?

Tags: python, html, pandas, parsing, beautifulsoup

I want to extract all relevant information from the URL below by date.
date start from 01/01/2009 until now.
Information are contents such as Date, RS/USD, 35.4049, 35.4929, etc...

I want all these types of data in a panda dataframe by date

```
import pandas as pd
import arrow
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import requests

url ="https://www.bom.mu/dealth-rate/downloadALL?field_dealing_date_value%5Bvalue%5D%5Bdate%5D=01-01-2009"


r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True) 
#open('google.ico', 'wb').write(r.content)

html_doc = r.content
html = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'lxml')
```

Can you help me?

Comment: So you want to append the value of date to url from pandas column automatically? Is this your question?

Comment: I want all the data contents in the tags for each date in a panda dataframe.

Comment: I'm unable to access that url, can you double check it? or let me know where it is on the website?